# JCodeModel and arrays

Tags: java

I can generate annotation class using JCodeModel exept one thing.
I can't understand how to add this to annotation:

```
@Target(value={METHOD,TYPE,CONSTRUCTOR})
```

How to set array of defined values as value of **value** method?
I can use param() method of JAnnotationUse class for simple annotations, but how to set array as value I can't find.

Answer (score 0):

Make something similar to this:

```
JAnnotationUse annotation = (JClass/JMethod/JFieldVar).annotate(Class<? extends java.lang.annotation.Annotation> MyAnnotation.class);
// Check if the value of the parameter of the annotation is an Array.
if (paramAnnotationValue.getClass().isArray()) {
    Object[] paramAnnotationValueArray = (Object[]) paramAnnotationValue;
    JAnnotationArrayMember annotationArrayMember = annotation.paramArray("parameter");
    for (Object paramValue : paramAnnotationValueArray) {
        annotationArrayMember.param((String/Boolean/Class/JType) paramValue);
    }
}
// No Array is normal.
else { 
    (...)
}
```

Something like this is generated:

```
@MyAnnotation(parameter = {
    "value_a",
    "value_b"
})
```